# Conversion of an extensive list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

*I'm wanting to do something like bellow:*

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(3,3), columns = list("abc"))
```

...

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

*For:*

```
data = [[[69, 2.0], [69, 2.0], [64, 3.872983346207417], [71, 1.4142135623730951], [80, 4.0]],
        [[69, 2.0], [69, 2.0], [64, 3.872983346207417], [71, 1.4142135623730951], [80, 4.0]], 
        [[69, 2.0], [69, 2.0], [64, 3.872983346207417], [71, 1.4142135623730951], [80, 4.0]]]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape([[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]]), columns = list("abcde"))
```

*But there was a problem in code:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape([[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]]), columns = list("abcde"))
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any suggetions?

> *Note: The bigger data grow exponentially*

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not add the `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(data, columns = list("abcde"))
           a          b  ...                         d          e
0  [69, 2.0]  [69, 2.0]  ...  [71, 1.4142135623730951]  [80, 4.0]
1  [69, 2.0]  [69, 2.0]  ...  [71, 1.4142135623730951]  [80, 4.0]
2  [69, 2.0]  [69, 2.0]  ...  [71, 1.4142135623730951]  [80, 4.0]
[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= data)
df.columns = list("abcde")
```

Output:

```
           a          b                        c                         d         e
0  [69, 2.0]  [69, 2.0]  [64, 3.872983346207417]  [71, 1.4142135623730951] [80, 4.0]
1  [69, 2.0]  [69, 2.0]  [64, 3.872983346207417]  [71, 1.4142135623730951] [80, 4.0]
2  [69, 2.0]  [69, 2.0]  [64, 3.872983346207417]  [71, 1.4142135623730951] [80, 4.0]
```

Comment: It was exactly what I wanted to do, thank you very much, you did it very quickly, I hope to reach your level one day